# How to grant Power BI Embedded permissions to native app registration with non-admin user with AAD v2 endpoint?

Tags: permissions, azure-active-directory, registration, sql-grant, powerbi-embedded

I've the following situation:

for each customer I've a React application that uses a Power BI Embedded Capacity to show reports and dashboards.
I've one user (customer.username@example.com) with a Power BI Pro license I can use for Power BI Embedded. This user is the admin of the Power BI Embedded Capacity and is the contributor of the azure subscription.
To allow the users (in the same Azure Actire Directory) that access this application to see the reports  and dashboards published I registered the application on the Azure Active Directory with a native registration and I added the following permissions related to Azure Active Directory Graph and Power BI Service:

1. User.Read
2. Capacity.Read.All
3. Capacity.ReadWrite.All
4. Content.Create.All
5. Dashboard.Read.All
6. Dashboard.ReadWrite.All
7. Dataset.ReadWrite.All
8. Group.Read
9. Report.ReadWrite.All
10. Workspace.Read.All
11. Workspace.ReadWrite.All

All the above permissions are Delegated permissions and don't require the admin consent.
This application and the app registration are created and deployed 
automatically and repetitively several times, one for each customer, via a PowerShell script and ARM template.

In the previous version of the App Registration tab (Identity Platform v1.0), once selected the native app registration, I'm able to navigate to Settings>Permissions and click on the Grant Permission button.
After the click on this button all the user on the same Azure Active Directory tenat can see the reports and dashboard in the application.
The above procedure is explained in this [video] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgiAUsdnVrM) (after minute 4).

Few days ago Microsoft replaced the tab with a new one (Identity Platform v2.0). In this version there is a new "Grant admin consent" button that can be cilcked only by an admin user. In my case I cannot use an admin user and the users of the new web applications are unable to see the reports and dashboards.

How can I grant the permissions (in the portal or via script/code) to use Power BI by the user that are using the new application?